# create alias to ssh to a server and then connect to mysql

Tags: linux, ssh, unix, terminal, alias

I currently have an alias to connect to a remote server:

> alias server='ssh user@ec2-00-00-00-000.compute-1.amazonaws.com'

I would like to have an alias to connect to this server, and then automatically open mysql terminal.

Currently, I connect to the server and then run:

> mysql

manually.

Is there anything like:

> alias serverdb='ssh user@ec2-00-00-00-000.compute-1.amazonaws.com && mysql'

but to be executed on the remote server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leave off the `&&`.  It probably will work better if you force a tty as well (the `-tt` below).

```
alias serverdb='ssh -tt user@ec2-00-00-00-000.compute-1.amazonaws.com mysql'
```